# Using the reorder function within geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Beginner to R, and here is my beginner question: I would like to know how to use the reorder function within geom_point

if I run my code (below), the figure will arrange the x axis according to number order 1,2,3,5 of the first number in "Split_time" column, and not the order I would want: `m_5,m_10,m_20,m_30`.

What would be the appropriate change here?

This is my data set:

```
Group Split_time ES 
Heavy m_5 -0.753006245 
Heavy m_10 -0.946046493 
Heavy m_20 -0.766883256
 Heavy m_30 -0.6175288 
Optimal m_5 -1.041742539 
Optimal m_10 -1.253699539
 Optimal m_20 -1.153807339
 Optimal m_30 -1.179895776 
Control m_5 -0.503250366 
Control m_10 -0.476303945 
Control m_20 -0.543155436
 Control m_30 -0.54148328
```

Code:

```
ggplot(SledESsplittimes2, aes(x = Split_time, y = ES, col = Group)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Does the following help? `ggplot(SledESsplittimes2, aes(x = factor(Split_time, levels = unique(df$Split_time)), y = ES, col = Group)) + 
  geom_point()`. This kind of assumes the column in ordered in the way you want.  Otherwise, you can manually set the levels in `factor()` to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It unfortunately gave me this error message: Error in df$Split_time : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Oh I apologise, that should probably have been `SledESsplittimes2$Split_time`

Answer (score 0):

It is because that column is of type character and when characters are sorted, "1" comes before "5" (so "m_10" comes before "m_5").

The data type in R that is used for categorical variables is called "factor". Read more on https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html and https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/factor

In your case, you can convert `Split_time` to a factor, and specify the levels manually in the order that you like them.

```
df$Split_time = factor(df$Split_time, levels = c("m_5", "m_10", "m_20", "m_30"))
```

Once you do that, ggplot will also order the factor based on its levels, with m_5 coming before m_10